# Как спозиционировать элементы на странице как на макете

Tags: css3

Как спозиционировать вот эти две строки, которые идут после логотипа, как на макете?

[image: Макет]

У меня не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Cargo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-header">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-inner">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png">
                        <div class="logo-text">CARGO</div>
                        <div class="span-logo">KALLYAS</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header-info">
                        <div class="logout" href="#">logout</div>
                        <div class="languages"><img src="../img/earth.png">languages</div>
                        <div class="social-icons">
                            <a class="icons" href="https://facebook.com"><img src="../img/fb.png"></a>
                            <a class="icons" href="https://twitter.com"><img src="../img/tw.png"></a>
                            <a class="icons" href="https://instagram.com"><img src="../img/inst.png"></a>
                            <form class="form">
                                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search..."></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="header-nav">
                        <a class="link" href="#">HOME</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">COMPANY</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">GLOBAL COVERAGE</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">NEWS</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                        <button class="btn">REQUEST QUOTE</button>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- /.header-inner -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header><!-- /.header -->
    </div><!-- /.main-header -->
</body>

</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1335px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-header {
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 780px;
}

/* Header Logo */

.header-logo {
    width: 188px;
    height: 188px;
    background-color: #181834;
}

.logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.98;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 69px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    margin-right: 69px;
}

.logo-text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.span-logo {
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Header Info*/

.header-info {
    display: flex;
}

.logout {
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.languages img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    opacity: 0.63;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.languages {
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.icons {
    width: 10px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

/* Form */

.form {
    display: inline-block;
}

.input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 34px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.38;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

input {
    margin-top: -8px;
}

/* Nav */

.header-nav {
    margin-top: 115px;
}

.link {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.btn {
    width: 176px;
    height: 58px;
    background-color: #0d5195;
    border: none;

    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя всё получится.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  padding: 0 3rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo actions actions" "logo navigation quoteButton";
  justify-items: end;
}

.header > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.actions {
  grid-area: actions;
  width: 50%;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: navigation;
  width: 50%;
}

.get-quote {
  grid-area: quoteButton;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="actions"></div>
  <nav class="navigation"></nav>
  <button class="get-quote">Request A Quote</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Поняла, что надо осваивать гриды — меньше кода. У меня получилось спозиционировать самой с помощью flex и relative и absolute позиционирование.

[image: что получилось]

```
    <body>
    <div class="main-header">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-inner">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png">
                        <div class="logo-text">CARGO</div>
                        <div class="span-logo">KALLYAS</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header-info">
                        <div class="logout" href="#">logout</div>
                        <div class="languages"><img src="../img/earth.png">languages</div>
                        <div class="social-icons">
                            <a class="icons" href="https://facebook.com"><img src="../img/fb.png"></a>
                            <a class="icons" href="https://twitter.com"><img src="../img/tw.png"></a>
                            <a class="icons" href="https://instagram.com"><img src="../img/inst.png"></a>
                            <form class="form">
                                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search..."></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="header-nav">
                        <a class="link active" href="#">HOME</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">COMPANY</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">GLOBAL COVERAGE</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">NEWS</a>
                        <a class="link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                        <button class="btn">REQUEST QUOTE</button>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- /.header-inner -->

                <div class="title">
                    <h1 class="h1">Ground, Air or Sea</h1>
                    <h2 class="h2">WE DELIVER YOUR PACKAGE IN NO-TIME</h2>
                    <img class="img" src="../img/triangle.png">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header><!-- /.header -->
    </div><!-- /.main-header -->
</body>
```

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1335px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-header {
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 780px;
}

/* Header Logo */

.header-logo {
    width: 188px;
    height: 188px;
    background-color: #181834;
}

.logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.98;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 69px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    margin-right: 69px;
}

.logo-text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.span-logo {
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Header Info*/

.header-info {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    right: 255px;
}

.logout {
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.languages img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    opacity: 0.63;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.languages {
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.icons {
    width: 10px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

/* Form */

.form {
    display: inline-block;
}

.input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    width: 220px;
    max-height: 34px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.38;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

input {
    margin-top: -8px;
}

/* Nav */

.header-nav {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    right: 255px;
}

.link {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 34px;
    transition: color .2s linear;
}

.link.active {
    position: relative;
}

.link:hover {
    color: #0d5195;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.link.active:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #f9f8f4;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 12px;
}

.btn {
    width: 174px;
    height: 58px;
    background-color: #0d5195;
    border: none;

    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f9f8f4;
    margin-left: 48px;
    margin-top: -21px;
}

/* Title */

.h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #0d5195;

    position: absolute;
    top: 365px;
    right: 477px;
}

.h2 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #0d5195;

    position: absolute;
    top: 445px;
    right: 366px;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 435px;
    right: 242px;
}
```